# Convert Map to ArrayList where entry value = something

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am using `Map<User, Integer>` and I need to select Users with specific Integers and add them to ArrayList, what is the easiest way to get all Users into `ArrayList<User>` where the Integer = 1?

This is what I tried, it works, but I would appreciate shorter code.

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList();

for (Map.Entry<User, Integer> entry : userAnswers.entrySet())
{
    if(entry.getValue()==1) users.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

EDIT: Thank you Danil Gaponov, your answer is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Electing the best one requires more explanation about your context and constraints.

Comment: Wait, so many are typing their answers. BTW, did you try anything ?

Comment: What means the `best way`?

Comment: What doesn't work about your code?

Comment: @Jens The most simple code to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requires Java 8:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(1))
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Just wanted to propose the same, but maybe you could add some explanation, esp. required Java version...

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote your post at least 10x for providing a simple line to do it and not asking what I have tried and what means the best way...

Comment: This method takes always more time than the "iterate over the map" method. Run a few tests with both methods if your map is very large.
For small maps, the difference should not be above a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

Create a generic static method:

```
public static <K, V> List<K> collectKeys(Map<K, V> map, V v) {
    List<K> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : map.entrySet()) 
        if (Objects.equals(e.getValue(), v))  // null-safe comparison
            list.add(e.getKey());
    return list;
}
```

Then simply:

```
users = collectKeys(userAnswers, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easier way to do it. Using a for loop and if is about as simple as Java gets.

Why do you think there should be an easier way? Perhaps you're not doing what I think when you say:

> with for and if Integer == 1, add to the ArrayList

If you post what you've done we can see if there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for code simplicity, you could also use [proton pack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) utilities for Java 8 with this simple line.

```
MapStream.of(map).inverseMapping().collect();
```